# curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid

Tags: 20.04, certificates

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20210119~20.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

ubuntu@ubuntu⍨$
```

Comment: You may want to verify your certificate dates. If the current time is not between `notBefore` and `notAfter`, then it cannot be used.